# In a computer with Cache, can the CPU directly interact with the main memory？

Tags: caching, memory, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

If a cache miss occurs, is there any specific hardware that copies the missing data into the cache, and then the CPU accesses the cache again? Or does the CPU directly access memory while a specific hardware copies the missing data into the cache at the same time?

The textbook confused me when it mentioned the direct interaction between the CPU and memory. I was unsure whether there was a cache involved during that process.

Comment: Usually, the CPU just asks the cache subsystem. If the line is not present, it will be fetched and stored accordingly to the cacheability of the request. Even in case of uncacheable requests, the CPU asks the cache that will fetch the data from memory (or serve it, it depends on the architecture). This doesn't make things slower as the cache also acts as an adapter between the CPU core and memory controller. So it's like an egress point for load/stores.

Comment: Cache is part of the path between CPU and memory, not a separate thing somewhere else.  Data arriving at the CPU from memory goes into L1d cache at the same time as the CPU pipeline makes the load result available to later instructions.  ("Early restart" and "critical word first" mean the CPU can start executing on arrival of the one part of the cache line it was waiting for, not the whole line; that keeps transferring in later cycles if the data path isn't as wide as a whole cache line.)

Comment: If you quote exactly what your textbook said, then we'd be able to explain it.